# JS: Custom JS validation not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, validation, internet-explorer, jquery-form-validator

I'm facing an issue with form validation in Internet Explorer.

In the following script, I have created a form in `HTML`, and wrote JavaScript logic to perform form validations before submitting the form.

The script validates the form properly and gives the alerts only in Chrome and Firefox BUT NOT in Internet Explorer, and I wonder why?:

http://jsfiddle.net/PKLQn/121/

```js
var error="";

function Checkfiles() {
    var fup = document.getElementById('flUpload');
    var fileName = fup.value;
    var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var chkext = ext.toLowerCase();
    //var mime = fup.type;
    //if (mime=='image/png' || mime=='image/jpeg' || mime=='image/gif') {
    if(chkext=="gif" || chkext=="jpg" || chkext=="jpeg" || chkext=="png") { 
        return true;
    } else { return false; }
} // Checkfiles

function Checksize() { 
    var iSize;
    if ($("#flUpload")[0].files[0]){
        iSize = ($("#flUpload")[0].files[0].size / 1024);
    }
    if(Checkfiles()==true) {
        if (iSize < 51200.00) { 
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    } else { error += "- Upload GIF, PNG, JPG images only, smaller than 50 KB."; return false; }
} //Checksize

function Checkfields() {
    // Validate Email
    var email = $("#email").val();
    if (/(.+)@(.+){2,}\.(.+){2,}/.test(email)) { } else { error += "- Please enter a valid email address (eg. http://youwebsite.com)\n"; }
    // Validate Title
    var title = $("#title").val();
    if (title=="" || title==null) { error += "- Please enter a valid title for your advertisement (Max. 60 chars.)\n"; }    
    // Validate URL
    var url = $("#url").val();
    if (/^(http[s]?:\/\/){0,1}(www\.){0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,5}[\.]{0,1}/.test(url)) { } else { error += "- Please enter a valid URL.\n"; }
}// Checkfields

function newfuncion() {
        var fields = Checkfields();
        var size = Checksize();
        var files = Checkfiles();
        if(fields==true && size==true && files==true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if(error!=""){alert(error); error=""; return false;} else {return true;}
            return false;
        }
} //Juntar todas las funciones
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 3px 8px;
  margin: 5px 0px 5px 10px;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.submit-btn {
  background: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="fff1" onsubmit="return newfuncion();">
    <label for="email">Email: </label> <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="email" /><br/>
    <label for="title">Title: </label> <input type="text" placeholder="Title" id="title" /><br/>
    <label for="url">URL: </label> <input type="text" placeholder="URL" id="url" /><br><br>
    <input type="file" id="flUpload" /><br/><br>
    <input type="submit" class="submit-btn" value="CONTINUE" />
</form>
```

I wonder why my code is not working on Internet Explorer 8, 9?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I honestly don't know how to check that, I tested on Internet Explorer 8 and after a few hours I got desperated, so I decided to drop support for IE8 and updated to Internet Explorer 9.. But has the same problem :(

Comment: In IE9 [press F12](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ie/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx) to bring up the dev tools (including the console). then try your function again and see if any errors are displayed.

Comment: not concerning this particular problem, but `http://youwebsite.com`, as suggested by your error message, is not an email address.

Comment: The error message is "Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference", btw, and the problem is the `$("#flUpload")[0].files[0]`. There is no ".files".

Comment: That's why Im validating, when there are no files also it will bring the alert, it works fine in Chrome and firefox

Answer (score 2):

IE 8/9 doesn't support "multifile" uploads, so the [`.files`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) property of the `<input type="file">` returns null. You try to access its first index, as if it returned an array, giving the error `"Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference`. It's also worth noticing that the `.size` property was not available before HTML5 and your code should check for that too. You can't check the file size only with JavaScript in older browsers.

Since you are not using multifile upload (at least not per your example code), you can check the presence of a file to be uploaded with `input.value`. Try changing the `.files[0]` to `.value` and changing the logic of the file size check and that should fix your problem in all browsers.

Comment: User will only upload one single file, not multiple. Or how can I modify that line in order to still getting that file size

Comment: Sadly you can't get file size in older browsers. You can always check it on the server-side after the user has posted the form.
If checking the file size *before* uploading is a real requirement you can try using some Flash Uploader.

Comment: Thanks man, a quick question. Do you know how can I target that function Checksize() only to work with all browsers except for IE ?

Comment: This is called "_browser spoofing_" and is not a recommended practice, although easily achievable (since you're using jQuery, check the [`$.browser`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) object). You can, however, check if the browser (whatever it is) supports the features you need (it's called "_feature detection_"). For this `.size` thing, you can do something like `if ($("#flUpload")[0].files) { /* check size */ } else { /* non-HTML5 browser */ }`
This may be overkill for your current issue, but you should check the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/docs/) library for _feature detection_.